# how to get-content of text file on multiple servers using powershell

Tags: file-get-contents

I'm trying to see if I can read a specific txt file (last x rows) on multiple servers.

I have tried this but its incorrect, can you please help me out?

Get-Content C:\Users\admin\server.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-Content "C:\project\file.log"  | Select -Last 20}

The file is located on the same folder on each server.
The server.txt has all server names to which i have access with my current user, like
Server1
Server2
Server3

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

okay, guessing your server.txt file contains server names like \Server1 \Server2 with a line containing a single server name? What I see is wrong is this.

1) Change your ForEach to 
    Foreach-object($*)
2) Inside your Foreach build the correct path. The $* var will be \Server1 so append \c$\Project\file.log

Not sure why the underscore is not showing up but the $ needs an underscore after it.

Comment: thanks for helping out, i found the thing:
 $server_names = Get-Content "C:\Users\hostlist.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names) {Get-Content "\\$server\c$\file.log" | Select -Last 20}

showing me last 20 rows of the log file

Answer (score 0):

$server_names = Get-Content "C:\Users\hostlist.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names) {Get-Content "\$server\c$\test.log" | Select -Last 20}